# PHP array_reduce with initial parameter as an array

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, reduce

I have this initial array:

```
[
    0 => ['id' => 5, 'value' => 50],
    1 => ['id' => 6, 'value' => 60],
    2 => ['id' => 7, 'value' => 70],
]
```

and want to convert it to:

```
[
    5 => ['value' => 50],
    6 => ['value' => 60],
    7 => ['value' => 70],
]
```

At first, I tried to use `map`, but it can't modify the array keys, so I thought `reduce` would solve the problem because it *reduces* the array to a single value, in this case, an array. So I tried:

```
array_reduce(
    $array,
    function($carry, $item) {
        return $carry[$item['id']] = $item['value'];
    },
    []
);
```

But it returns this error `Cannot use a scalar value as an array`. What am I doing wrong? Does `array_reduce` cannot receive an array as an initial value?

Comment: did you need to use array function or manual will be okey?

Comment: I'm trying to do it as functional as I can, I know a simple foreach would solve the problem.

Comment: Not really what array_reduced is supposed to do at all: `$newArray = array_column($oldArray, 'value', 'id'); array_walk($newArray, function(&$value) { $value = ['value' => $value]; });` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/nWdfg)

Comment: Oh, that works. If you post the answer I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Mark Baker`did it. I also did with `foreach` loop.

```
$arr = array(
            array('id' => 5, 'value' => 50),
            array('id' => 6, 'value' => 60),
            array('id' => 7, 'value' => 70)
        );

$result = array();
$result = array_column($arr, 'value', 'id'); 
array_walk($result, function(&$value) { $value = ['value' => $value]; });


//I did this using foreach loop, But the OP need it through array function.
//foreach($arr as $key => $value){
//    $result[$value['id']] = array('value' => $value['value']);
//}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [value] => 50
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [value] => 60
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [value] => 70
        )

)
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `array_reduce` didn't work because You weren't returning the accumulator array (`carry` in Your case) from the callback function.

```
array_reduce(
    $array,
    function($carry, $item) {
        $carry[$item['id']] = $item['value'];
        return $carry; // this is the only line I added :)
    },
    []
);
```

I came to this question while looking for a way to use `array_reduce`, so I felt I should write this comment. I hope this will help future readers. :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer I think. I was doing return $list[$client->ID] = $client->post_title; which didn't produce the correct array if I just put it on its own line and hten returned list it worked.

Comment: @ChristopherKarlsson thank You! I am glad this helped with Your issue :) However, I will let the author decide whether this will become the accepted answer. I think he already did, but it' never too late. Regards, Aleksandar

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the best solutions are the simplest. Loop through your array and assign the id and value to a new array.

```
$new_array = array();    
foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
    $new_array[$arr['id']] = array('value' => $arr['value']);
}
```

Comment: I know, i know, is just that I wanted to do it as functional as possible. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I totally get that. I think the issue would be with using array_map or array_walk is that you would have an issue converting the keys/indexes i.e. from 0 to 5. At least this way it's very little code for the results you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it functionally. I suspect it's not actually more readable however.

```
array_combine(
    array_column($a, 'id'), 
    array_map(function($v) { return ['value' => $v['value']]; }, $a)
);
```

Or even...

```
array_map(
  function($v) { return ['value' => $v['value']]; }, 
  array_column($a, null, 'id')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_reduce($ar, function ($acc, $item) {
        $acc[$item['id']] = [ 'value' => $item['value']]; 
        return $acc;
    }, [])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.